# How to get GUID encoder, if i have a pointer on IMFTransform?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ms-media-foundation

I have a pointer on IMFTransform *pEncoder. How can i get GUID encoder from this pointer, if IMFTransform::GetAttributes return E_NOTIMPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Foundation transforms don't have to expose their CLSID, they don't even have to have them at all. They don't even have to be instantiatable via `CoCreateInstance`. More to that, for even standard encoders Media Foundation suggests enumeration and activation objects rather than direct instantiation from CLSID.

If you have an interface pointer of an encoder MFT, your best bet is to check attributes and also query one of the well known `IPersistXxx` interfaces - there is a chance but not a guarantee that you can capture a CLSID.